# Read Datagrid in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How to Read whole datagrid using Actionscript, that Datagrid contains Combobox itemrenderer and Textbox itemrenderer in two coloumn, I want to read the value of both the itemrenderer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't need to loop through the `DataGrid` to get the values from the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` item renderers. Just read through the `ArrayCollection` or whatever you're using as the `DataGrid`'s `dataProvider`.

Comment: But dataprovider will not gives us Itemrenderer selected value

Comment: @user663705, It will if you set the dataProviders value when the selected value is changed in your itemRenderer. `<s:ComboBox id="myComboBox" change="data.MyField = myComboBox.selectedItem">`